# Meaning of 'duty' here

Tags: meaning-in-context, legalese

> His case, though, was rejected by the Court of Appeal, which suggested
>   that practical and policy reasons militated against allowing him to recover damages. Lord
>   Justice Stuart-Smith said:
>
> > In my judgment both as a matter of principle and policy the court should not
> >     extend the **duty** to those who are mere bystanders or witnesses of horrific events
> >     unless there is a sufficient degree of proximity, which requires both nearness in
> >     time and place and a close relationship of love and affection between plaintiff and
> >     victim.

Would someone please explain how to determine which definition of [duty](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/duty?q=duty) applies here?
I can't distinguish. Definition 1 looks correct, if I consider **duty** as 'responsibility of the law'. Yet Definition 3 looks right too, if **duty = payment** (in the form of damages) ?

Source: P95, How the Law Works, Gary Slapper

Comment: duty is definitely talking about responsibility here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context, context, context! You establish the meaning by reading the passage in its larger context.

It is provided in sufficient part [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=RYgrvyWchbcC&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=%22the+court+should+not+extend+the+duty+to+those+who+are+mere+bystanders+or+witnesses+of+horrific+events%22&source=bl&ots=qHGMxwqN3r&sig=FOujB24yxXP5Jsunyk3zYvCur60&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UXi6U_rsEseLyASEg4KQAw&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22the%20court%20should%20not%20extend%20the%20duty%20to%20those%20who%20are%20mere%20bystanders%20or%20witnesses%20of%20horrific%20events%22&f=false).

There it is made clear that the *duty* involved is the **duty of care**: the legal obligation of one person to provide medical relief for illness or injury suffered by another.

This particular sentence was uttered in the decision respecting a case where an employee who witnessed a terrible accident at the oilrig where he worked sued his employer for the nervous shock he suffered. The Court here holds that that **duty** should not extend to the employer in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

[Duty](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/duty), in the sense of responsibility, [burden](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/burden) or [obligation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/obligation).

**duty (ˈdjuːtɪ)**

1. a task or action that a person is bound to perform for moral or legal reasons